# Can you create custom breakpoints with LESS mixins?

Tags: css, less, media-queries

Most of the time, I use LESS variables with preset breakpoints for media queries like this:

```
@s-max : ~"screen and (max-width: 40em)";
@m-max : ~"screen and (max-width: 50em)";
@l-max : ~"screen and (max-width: 60em)";

USAGE

.some-class {
    color: red;

    @media @s-max {
       color: blue;
    }
}
```

But sometimes, I would like to be able to refer to an arbitrary breakpoint in my .less stylesheet without having to set a new preset value in my separate mixin file.

You can do this in SASS. The mixin looks like this:

```
@mixin bp-min($canvas) {

    @media only screen and (min-width:$canvas) {@content;}
}

USAGE

@include bp-min(750px) {

//responsive styling for min-width of 750px

}
```

In LESS, I'm imagining the equivalent mixin would look something like this:

```
.bp-min(@min) {

    @media only screen and (min-width:@min)...
}
```

The only problem is, the lack of the {@content} argument in LESS, which grabs the rest of the styling inputted by the developer. I love SASS, but I can't use it at work.

Does anyone know of a LESS-based solution to this problem?

Comment: This is one reason i moved from LESS to SCSS. There was no support for this when I moved.

Comment: And there are other good reasons to move as well.

Comment: I know, I know. Sass is a beautiful thing. I'm considering (not very seriously) moving some of my personal projects off of it to LESS, just so I can stop being reminded of what I'm missing out on at work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using Pattern Matching

I believe this achieves what you want:

**LESS**

```
/* generic caller */
.bp-min(@min) {
    @media only screen and (min-width:@min) {
      .bp-min(@min, set);
    }
}

/* define them */
.bp-min(750px, set) {
  test: (@min - 300px);
}
.bp-min(400px, set) {
  test: (@min - 100px);
}

/* call them */
.bp-min(750px);
.bp-min(400px);
```

**Output CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  test: 450px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  test: 300px;
}
```

By defining a `set` pattern mixin for the various sizes, and then using that pattern within the generic `.bp-min(@min)` mixin, I believe we have the same abstraction in LESS that you have in SCSS, with slightly more code because I believe SCSS defines and calls in one `@include` statement, whereas here we need two.

Comment: interesting approach. it seems to require about the same amount of time/work as just creating another preset media query (with a @variable), but I'll think more on this solution and see if I can use it. Thanks!

Comment: It may not be much less work, but the key point I want to make is that it is hardly different than the SCSS version you gave as an example of what you were hoping to achieve. The only extra is the invocation of the calls to start the process rolling.

Comment: i see what you mean. It's just that my lazy mind wants something just as quick and easy and mindless as sass makes it... but it looks like you may have come up with the next best thing in LESS. thanks.

Answer (score 15):

## It is now similar to SASS

As of [1.7.0](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (2014-02-27) you can now use @rules in place of the sassy @content.

For example:

```
.breakpoint-small(@rules) {
  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) { @rules(); }
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  .breakpoint-small({
    width: 50%;
  });
}
```

outputs, as expected:

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

The differences being:

- function takes @rules as an argument
- additional parenthesis when invoking the function
- '.' syntax as opposed to '@include'

This can be combined with an additional argument to provide syntax equivalent to a nice bit of sass:

```
.breakpoint(@size, @rules) {
  @media screen and (min-width: @size) { @rules(); }
}

@large: 60em;
ul {
  .breakpoint(@large, {
    width: 50%;
  });
}
```

**edit**: To be honest I prefer a way more simple approach in less:

```
@break-large: ~"screen and (min-width: 60em)";
ul {
  @media @break-large {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Source: I too use sass at home and less at work

Comment: your last one looks great so far

Answer (score 2):

(In addition to the prev. answer) Or something like this:

```
.bp-min(@canvas) {
    @media only screen and 
        (min-width: @canvas) {.content}
}

// usage:

& { .bp-min(900px); .content() {
    color: red;
}}

& { .bp-min(600px); .content() {
    color: blue;
}}

// more usage examples:

.class-green { 
    .bp-min(450px); .content() {
        color: green;
}}

& { .bp-min(300px); .content() {

    .class-yellow {
        color: yellow;
    }

    .class-aqua {
        color: aqua;
    }
}}
```

Replace `.content` with `.-` if you prefer shorter stuff.

Comment: I actually like this approach a little better than the first, since the usage all happens in one place/selector. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed my variables to reference other variables, so some of these solutions did not work. Here is what I went with.

```
@bp-xs: ~"screen and (max-width:"@screen-xs-max~")";
@bp-sm: ~"screen and (max-width:"@screen-sm-max~")";
@bp-md: ~"screen and (max-width:"@screen-md-max~")";
@bp-lg: ~"screen and (max-width:"@screen-lg-max~")";
```

and then use them like so

```
@media @bp-sm {
  ...
}
```